# SQL Server Windows authentication untrusted domain

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a question: I have to connect to a SQL Server using Windows authentication. When I try to login from SSMS, all works well, but when I try to login from a .NET app using VS2017, I get this error:

> Login Failed. The Login is From an Untrusted Domain and Cannot be Used with Windows Authentication

The server is not on my computer.

The same error appears if I want to use the same connection string from SISS package.

What might be the issue?

Comment: have you used Integrated Security=true?